# How to derive $¬X \lor ¬Y \lor ¬Y$ from $Z ⊃ (¬X \lor ¬Y)$ and $¬Z ⊃ ¬ Y$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that one can derive $¬X \lor ¬Y  \lor ¬Y$ (which simplifies to $¬X \lor ¬Y$, right?) from $Z ⊃ (¬X \lor ¬Y)$ and  $¬Z ⊃ ¬ Y$ but I don't know how you do this.

Maybe one just has to use constructive dilemma?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use $¬Z \lor Z$ and [Constructive dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dilemma).

Or you can use $¬Z \lor Z$ and *Proof by cases* :

1) $¬Z \lor Z$

2) $Z⊃(¬X∨¬Y)$

3) $¬Z⊃¬Y$

4) $¬Y⊃(¬X∨¬Y)$ --- [Disjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)

5) $¬Z⊃(¬X∨¬Y)$ --- from 3) and 4) by [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism)

> 6) $¬X \lor ¬Y$ --- from 1) 2) and 5) by [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

And then again Disjunction introduction to get: $(¬X∨¬Y)∨¬Y$

Comment: I see how this works for constructive dilemma, but I don't see it clearly for proof by cases. Could you please spell it out?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand step 4 (disjunction introduction)

Comment: @Mijito - click with the mouse on the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Hypothetical Syllogism and Contraposition, you can do it without having to assume $Z \lor \neg Z$:

$1. Z \rightarrow (\neg X \lor \neg Y) \quad Premise$

$2. \neg Z \rightarrow \neg Y \quad Premise$

$3. Y \rightarrow Z \quad Contraposition \ 2$

$4. Y \rightarrow (\neg X \lor \neg Y) \quad Hypothetical \ Syllogism \ 1,3$

$5. \neg Y \lor \neg X \lor \neg Y \quad Implication \ 4$

$6. \neg X \lor  \neg Y \lor \neg Y \quad Commutation \ 5$

Comment: Sure, although "Implication" in 5 is basically ... $$\def\fitch#1#2{~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\begin{split}&\fitch{Y\to W}{Y\vee\neg Y \qquad\star\\\fitch{Y}{W\\\neg Y\vee W}\quad \raise{1.5ex}{\fitch{\neg Y}{\neg Y\vee W}}\\\neg Y\vee W}\\\hline  Y\to W&\vdash \neg Y\vee W\end{split}$$